# Drawing a cube with GlDrawElements()?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Is there a way to draw a cube like this and as a result, only upload 8 verticies and 24 indicies to the graphics card? If so how could this be done?

Thanks

I currently do it like this:

```
boxdims.x = w;
    boxdims.y = h;
    boxdims.z = d;
    center = c;

    GLfloat vboverticies[72];
    GLfloat vbonormals[18];
    Vertex3f verticies[24];

    //Top face
    verticies[0] = Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[1] = Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[2] = Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[3] = Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);


    //Bottom face
    verticies[4] = Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[5] = Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[6] = Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[7] = Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);


    //Left face
    verticies[8] = Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[9] = Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[10] =Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[11] =Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);


    //Right face
    verticies[12] =Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[13] =Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[14] =Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[15] =Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);

    //Front face
    verticies[16] =Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[17] =Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[18] =Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[19] =Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, boxdims.z / 2.0f);

    //Back face
    verticies[20] =Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[21] =Vertex3f(-boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[22] =Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);
    verticies[23] =Vertex3f(boxdims.x / 2.0f,-boxdims.y / 2.0f, -boxdims.z / 2.0f);




    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        verticies[i].x += center.x;
        verticies[i].y += center.y;
        verticies[i].z += center.z;
    }


    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
    {
        vboverticies[count] = verticies[i].x;
        count++;
        vboverticies[count] = verticies[i].y;
        count++;
        vboverticies[count] = verticies[i].z;
        count++;
    }

    //glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //glNormal3f(0.0, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    //glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    //glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    vbonormals[0] = (0.0);
    vbonormals[1] = (1.0);
    vbonormals[2] = (0.0);

    vbonormals[3] = (0.0);
    vbonormals[4] = (-1.0);
    vbonormals[5] = (0.0);

    vbonormals[6] = (-1.0);
    vbonormals[7] = (0.0);
    vbonormals[8] = (0.0);

    vbonormals[9] = (1.0);
    vbonormals[10]= (0.0);
    vbonormals[11]= (0.0);

    vbonormals[12]= (0.0);
    vbonormals[13]= (0.0);
    vbonormals[14]= (1.0);

    vbonormals[15]= (0.0);
    vbonormals[16]= (0.0);
    vbonormals[17]= (-1.0);



    //Create the VBO
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboID);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (72 * sizeof(GLfloat)) + 
        (18 * sizeof(GLfloat)) , NULL, GL_STATIC_COPY);

    glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0, 72 * sizeof(GLfloat), vboverticies);
    glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 72 * sizeof(GLfloat),
        18 * sizeof(GLfloat), vbonormals);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

If you need normals, you'll have to have 24 vertices, as no face shares normals. Note that the example provided by shk does not handle normals.

Comment: @Milo: Just like the link shk gave you. Use 8 vertices, and 24 indices, using glDrawElements()

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it'll be helpfull - http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html

Comment: Which of my verticies do I keep to = their 8 vertices (v0, v7)

Comment: @Milo one for each point of the cube... this would make vertices 0 to 7 inclusive, in your case. But beware the indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you'll have to use geometry shaders for that, and you should not mess with this stuff until you really know what you're doing. What's more, for just a cube, it's really not a big deal.